# Binding @media tag dynamically to element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create all my html/css from javascript code like that:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.setAttribute('id', 'fooBar');
el.style.width = "30%";
document.getElementById('body').appendChild(el);
```

It all works fine, but now I want to add `@media` tags to that code. The whole `html/css` code is appended to the body element, so it'd be best not to use ids or classes.

The only solution I found to do that is:

```
document.querySelector('style').textContent += 
    "@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) { fooBar { font-size: 11px; }}";
```

But it's bad cause it messes up with external styles, I'd prefer to do that locally. Also, it seems that it doesn't work for styles created dynamically like width or height.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You have no way to do this only in CSS? It's not the best thing to do to mix CSS in JS

Comment: I would disagree here, it's better to create css from javascript. But either way, it's external script included on websites where I won't be able to access DOM elements directly.

Comment: I would strongly recommend avoiding setting css in javascript unless there is no other way.

Answer (score 2):

You can just check the size of the screen.
And then applying the styles based on what the screen size is.
Probably also need to hook this to a screen resize event.

```
function sizeStyle() {
  if (screen.width >= 900) {
    [your javascript styles here]
  } else if (screen.width >= 600) {
    [other javascript style]
  }
}

window.onresize = function(event) {
  sizeStyle();
}; //resizing the window

sizeStyle(); //(before dom?) initial call
```